# How to display map object content in AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a map object in my angular controller like this,

```
var map = new Map();
map.set(1,'a');
map.set(2,'b');
map.set(3,'c');
map.set(4,'d');
$scope.map = map;
```

How do I display its content in my html file using ng-repeat?
I tried the following, they didn't work

```
    <div ng-repeat ="m in map">
        {{m}}
    </div>


    <div ng-repeat ="(key, value) in map">
        {{key}}
        {{value}}
    </div>
```

Comment: Simply: you, unfortunately, can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't as ng-repeat iterates over an array of objects. But you can use something like [Agular Filter GroupBy](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby) for that. Or change structure of your array to `[{key: 'key', value: 'value'},..]` and change ng-repeat to

```
<div ng-repeat ="item in map">
    {{item.key}}
    {{item.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: Not entirely accurate... ng-repeat also iterates objects

Comment: My bad. For some reason, I was missing that part of docs from migration to 1.4. And it was hidden even more deeply before that :)

Comment: Not a new feature...has always iterated objects

Comment: It was, yet I was always considering that as side-effect of iterator behaviour.